# Streaming data using Langchain RetrivalQA

Tags: python, django, openai-api, server-sent-events, langchain

I am using Django, and Langchain with OpenAI to generate responses to my prompts. I was trying to enable streaming using Server-Sent-Events (SSE) in my API function.
When I run my code It does stream the OpenAI output in the terminal, but it returns the output as a whole to the client once the streaming has ended.

I tried using StreamingHttpResponse but, didn't get any success. It would be really awesome if any one can suggest what's wrong in the code.

API Function:

```
@api_view(['GET','POST'])
def sse_view(request):
if request.method != 'POST':
    return Response({"message": "Use the POST method for the response"})

url = request.data.get("url")
questions = request.data.get("questions")
prompt = request.data.get("promptName")

if not url or not questions:
    return Response({"message": "Please provide valid URL and questions"})

# Process the documents received from the user
try:
    doc_store = process_url(url)
    if not doc_store:
        return Response({"message": "PDF document not loaded"})
except Exception as e:
    return Response({"message": "Error loading PDF document"})


custom_prompt_template = set_custom_prompt(url,prompt)
# Load and process documents
loader = DirectoryLoader(DATA_PATH, glob='*.pdf', loader_cls=PyPDFLoader)
documents = loader.load()   

text_splitter = CustomRecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1500, chunk_overlap=30)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)

#Creating Embeddings using OpenAI
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(chunk_size= 16, openai_api_key= openai_gpt_key,)

db = FAISS.from_documents(texts, embeddings)
db.save_local(DB_FAISS_PATH)
search_kwargs = {
    'k': 30,
    'fetch_k':100,
    'maximal_marginal_relevance': True,
    'distance_metric': 'cos',
}
retriever=db.as_retriever(search_kwargs=search_kwargs)

# get the list of questions from the body
questionList =request.data['questions']

#This function is to generate responses from OpenAi
def openai_response_generator():
        
        # Create an instance of ChatOpenAI
        llm = ChatOpenAI(
            model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
            streaming=True,
            callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()],
            temperature=0,
            openai_api_key= openai_gpt_key,
        )

        # Iterating through the questions list
        for question in (questionList):
            qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
                llm=llm,
                chain_type="stuff",
                retriever=retriever,
                return_source_documents=True,
                chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": custom_prompt_template},
            )

        res = qa({'query': question})
        yield f"data: {res['result']}\n\n"

response = StreamingHttpResponse(openai_response_generator(), content_type="text/event-stream")
return response
```

Here's what I see in PostMan when I run the function.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you use `Callback Handler` to handle the new stream from LLM

`langchain` provides many builtin callback handlers but we can use customized Handler

```
class CustomStreamingCallbackHandler(BaseCallbackHandler):
"""Callback Handler that Stream LLM response."""

    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue

    
    def on_llm_new_token(self, token: str, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
    """Run on new LLM token. Only available when streaming is enabled."""
        self.queue.put(token)
```

we are doing here that whenever OpenAI API streams a new token, we put it in a Queue.
Our Custom Handler Accept the queue and put tokens in that queue

Now, in the view we need to do this,

```
def generate_stream(q: Queue):
    #Any Custom Condition To stop while loop
    #like while the queue is not empty
    while (...):
        stream = q.get()
        yield stream

queue = Queue()
response = StreamingHttpResponse(generate_stream(queue), content_type="text/event-stream")
```

Apart from this, you need to start the primary `openai_response_generator` function on the thread

```
queue = Queue()
task = threading.Thread(
    target=openai_response_generator,
    args=(queue,)
)
task.start()
response = StreamingHttpResponse(generate_stream(queue), content_type="text/event-stream")
```

There will be a change in the openai_response_generator function

```
def openai_response_generator(queue):
    
    # Create an instance of ChatOpenAI
    llm = ChatOpenAI(
        model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
        streaming=True,
        temperature=0,
        openai_api_key= openai_gpt_key,
    )
    llm.callback_manager = CustomStreamingCallbackHandler(queue)
    # Iterating through the questions list
    for question in (questionList):
        qa = RetrievalQA.from_chain_type(
            llm=llm,
            chain_type="stuff",
            retriever=retriever,
            return_source_documents=True,
            chain_type_kwargs={"prompt": custom_prompt_template},
        )

    res = qa({'query': question})
```

**Summary of what happening here:**

While defining LLM, we set the `custom callback handler` which accepts the `queue` and puts the new streamed token in that queue, while in the view we return the `StreamingHttpResponse` using that queue,

That's it

Comment: how would you do streaming with a local llm and not OpenAI? E.g. a model loaded with llamacpp

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit out of date now and I may have misunderstood a little but it looks like you are building the qa object by iterating over the questions, but then only pass it once after the iterator finishes.  If you want questions answered individually do you not want to pass the questions in one by one (ie inside the iterator).